# Were commandants in Kamchatka from the Army or the Navy?

Tags: military, russia, 18th-century, kamchatka, siberia

The Imperial Russian Navy operated out of Kronstadt, next to St. Petersburg. Well before sending the *Nadezhda* and *Neva* into the Pacific in 1803, the empire had Pacific ports like Okhotsk, accessible by land from Yakutsk, as well as several in Kamchatka, generally reached by sea. Okhotsk had a shipyard, as well as a commandant who was tried by the Admiralty (thanks @PieterGeerkens), but I can't tell yet if the Kamchatka commandants were in the navy too.

During Catherine the Great's rule (1762-1796), to which military force and commandant were the Kamchatka detachments in Bolsheretsk and Nizhnekamchatsk responsible?

Comment: Any *Captain* in charge of a naval base is almost certainly a Naval Captain, which has three levels of seniority on an Army *Captain* (and who typically commands only a company of only about 150 men). Captain Bukharin was in fact a Naval Captain.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I've seen these locations described as ports, towns, or harbors, but never until now as naval bases. Where did you find out about Bukharin?

Comment: [I googled him](https://books.google.ca/books?id=rgskDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT172&lpg=PT172&dq=Captain+Bukharin&source=bl&ots=hrqDdCPcXW&sig=mTY_-X6TgfOhC_TImbq-nD1xbFc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq6avX7MbYAhWTw4MKHbwUAKsQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=Captain%20Bukharin&f=false). Since he reported to the Russian Admiralty, he must have been a Naval Captain.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that the command is with the most *relevant* officer.

E.g., an [amphibious operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibious_warfare) is commanded by the *naval* commander. I.e., when a ship lands an amphibious force on an enemy shore, the overall commanding officer is the ship's captain, not the amphibious force's commander. Moreover, even if the ship is lost and *all* troops are now ashore, the command remains with the ship's captain.

Similarly, a port will normally be commanded by a naval officer (unless it is under a land siege).

I know the answer is even broader than the question...

Comment: I dispute this in principle, without specific examples. There is, and has been for several centuries, an accepted correspondence between naval and non-naval ranks. It is my belief that the highest ranking officer has overall command, with ties broken by date of each officer's most recent commission. If the tie still stands by date, then service priority rules - Naval highest for Great Britain, Non-Naval highest for every European nation I can think of. Further, it doesn't answer the question asked either by officer or port.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: you are talking about _seniority_, I am talking about operational command. A junior officer may be in charge and give orders to a senior one.

Comment: As I told my (newly commissioned) son: Never make a significant decision without first asking your Sergeant for input. The *most senior* officer is still **responsible** for the overall command - but will delegate operational authority to appropriate less senior officers. There absolutely must be an unambiguous command structure at all times, and the only one that exists, that everyone knows their position in, is seniority. Otherwise everything hinges on only taking the *right* casualties

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: The situation when a Colonel reports to a Major was not unheard of in the Soviet Army. This is what I meant: an officer with a clear rank seniority is _not_ the commanding officer and takes orders from an officer of a lower rank.

Comment: I know more junior *political officers* at times held *veto* over orders - but I never heard of them having *operational command* over more senior officers. If absolutely necessary, that would typically be arranged by assigning a *brevet rank* for duration of the mission. That would be similar to the use of the title *Commodore* before it became an official rank.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: the is _no_ such thing as "brevet rank" in the Soviet/Russian Army. There are two separate (although statistically _correlated_) things: **rank** (as in "colonel" or "major") and **position** (as in "regiment commander" or "division commander"). If a major is appointed to command a division, he is a commanding officer of all his regiment commanders, some of whom may outrank him. At any rate these distinctions are not relevant to the question. My point is the in a naval theater, a naval officer would be appointed to command the mission.

Comment: Okay, I am rereading Gulag Archipelago now. It seems you are talking about the *blue-capped* political hierarchy as compared to the regular officers. Solzhenitsyn seems to be making clear that while at all times orders had to be approved by the political commissar, the highest ranking regular officer still always had sole responsibility for mission success.

Comment: Solzhenitsyn is not a very reliable source. I have no idea what "blue-capped" is.